# To get the nearest submit button using javascript

Tags: javascript

Following is a test code of what i want to achieve. I want to find the value of submit button when cancel is clicked. here i have use for loop. is there any other way without iterating.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<ol>
   <input type="text"  name="txt1">
   <input type="text"  name="txt2">
   <input type="text"  name="txt3">

  <li><input type="button" value="cancel" name="cancel"  onclick="myFunction()"></li>
  <li><input type="button" value="undo" name="undo"></li>
  <li><input type="submit" value="send mail" name="submit"></li>
</ol>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var elementsLI = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var length = document.getElementsByTagName('li').length;

    for(var i = 0; i <= length ; ++i){
        if(elementsLI[i].childNodes[0].type == "submit"){
            alert(elementsLI[i].childNodes[0].value);
        }
        //var y = elementsLI.childNodes[i].type == "submit";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not a valid markup

Comment: Why don't you just give the submit button an id like "submit" and search for it with document.getElementById("submit"); ?

Comment: this are dynamically generated and i cant change them. there is no id to any element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it using [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method with [attribute equals selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
var submit = document.querySelector('li [type="submit"]');
```